# Why is Spring exception handler not working as expected

Tags: spring-mvc

When I use `@ExceptionHandler` within Controller, it's not working as expected.

Here is my code:

```
@Controller
public class PageController {

    @RequestMapping("/page")
    public ModelAndView index(ModelAndView modelAndView){
        String mess = null;
        mess.split(",");
        modelAndView.setViewName("index");
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @ExceptionHandler({Exception.class})
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, reason = "Bad Request")
    public ModelAndView handleException(Exception ex, HttpServletRequest request,     HttpServletResponse response){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.addObject("message", ex.getMessage());
        modelAndView.addObject("url", request.getRequestURL());
        modelAndView.addObject("code", response.getStatus());
        modelAndView.setViewName("exception");
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

After the application starts with debug mode, I visit `http://localhost:8080/page`, and `handleException` is running, but the view is below other than the expected `excepction` view. Why?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is with the `@ResponseStatus` annotation. Have a look at the following article: http://blog.sizovs.net/spring-rest-exception-handler/. In the mid of this article the author says following:

> Warning: when using this annotation on an exception class, or when setting the reason attribute of this annotation, the `HttpServletResponse.sendError` method will be used.
>   With `HttpServletResponse.sendError`, the response is considered complete and should not be written to any further. Furthermore, the Servlet container will typically write an HTML error page therefore making the use of a reason unsuitable for REST APIs. For such cases it is preferable to use a `org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity` as a return type and avoid the use of `@ResponseStatus` altogether.

According to a Spring article: https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc, Spring MVC chains the following three resolvers in the order below:

> - ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver matches uncaught exceptions against for suitable @ExceptionHandler methods on both the handler (controller) and on any controller-advices.
> - ResponseStatusExceptionResolver looks for uncaught exceptions annotated by @ResponseStatus (as described in Section 1)
> - DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver converts standard Spring exceptions and converts them
>     to HTTP Status Codes (I have not mentioned this above as it is internal to Spring MVC).

So the `ResponseStatusExceptionResolver` is triggered after the `ExceptionHanlderExceptionResolver` and uses the default and will display Spring's error page.

For a quick fix try to remove `@ResponseStatus` and you should see your custom error page in your browser.